# Pass data from mat dialog back to component

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

So, this popup opens and I can write any data in textArea but unfortunately, on clicking Submit button pop up not closing and I am not getting value in ts file.
If I click outside the popup box I am getting Undefined value in TS.

I need solution for this.
1. Why TextArea Data not transferred into TS File ?
2. Popup must close after writing any data in TextArea and On-clicking button, Prevent the user clicking other portion of the Screen.

My ts Code is :

```
if(cnfrm){
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.callAPIDialog)
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`); // which will be value
})
}
```

My html code is:

```
 <ng-template #callAPIDialog> 
    <textarea #name matInput placeholder="Leave a comment" formControlName="description" required></textarea> 
    <button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close(name.value)">Submit</button> 
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: You need to look into controlValueAccessor possibly to ensure the value from the formControl is passed into your popup and "bound" Can you create a stackblitz example with what you are trying to do please?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: @JudsonTerrell Kindly look first one in given link

Comment: So you want to create a dialog with a text area that binds to the original form? Then when its closed or submitted the form will retain that value?

Comment: yes.. I need Dailog box(I am getting now), It should close and value to be pass to TS file

Comment: Please carefully look at the TS file etc. Are you trying to do exactly what they are doing in the link you provided and you are stating that it is not working? Also, you are using reactive forms, not template driven forms correct?

Comment: I will create an example...

Comment: @JudsonTerrell Its bit urgent.. R u know properly to do ?

Comment: @JudsonTerrell any solution ?

Comment: I am working on it now give me about 20 minutes

Comment: I have added my working example.

Comment: Also a good idea is always to explain your issue then provide your code. i will edit your question so you do not get downvoted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the correct way to implement in its most simple approach.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ott6js-hpfsuv?embed=1&file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts

The key here is to capture the data on change:

**The html:**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite Animal</mat-label>
    <input matInput (change)="changeAnimal($event)">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

**html 2**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<ol>
  <li>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>What's your name?</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="name">
    </mat-form-field>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="1==1">
    You chose: <i>{{myForm.controls.animal.value}}</i>
  </li>
</ol>
</form>
```

**The script**

```
import {Component,Input, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
}

/**
 * @title Dialog Overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['dialog-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DialogOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: new FormControl(null),
      animal: new FormControl(null)
    })
  }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      disableClose: true, // this prevents clicking outside
      width: '250px',
      data: this.myForm.value
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed', result);
      // this.myForm.setControl('animal', result);
      this.myForm.controls.animal.setValue(result);
    });
  }

}



//The dialog component. We are using ngValue accessor to get the values.
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {
  animal: string;
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
    changeAnimal(ev: any) {
      this.data.animal = ev.target.value;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please repeat?

Comment: I am asking, in Pop Up screen can we make input as Required field ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ott6js-hpfsuv?embed=1&file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts

Comment: Here is a more updated answer.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ott6js-hpfsuv

Comment: R u know Answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911230/expanding-in-angular-material